# Update a Label while the app is running without a button on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a label that keeps counting how many times the user typed a certain word(in this case "1r#") in a ScrolledText without needing to make a button to update the label.
Can I make a loop? If so, how could I do it?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = Tk()

dataFrame = Frame(root)
recFrame = Frame(root)

dataLabel = Label(root, text="Dados").grid(column=0, row=0)
dataInput = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=3, height=10)
dataInput.grid(column=0, row=1)

dataFrame.grid(column=0)

# Counts how many times the text appears
dataText = dataInput.get("1.0", "end-1c")
label = Label(recFrame, text=dataText)
labelCount = label['text'].count("1r#")


recPeTitle = Label(recFrame, text="P", width=3)
recPeTitle.grid(column=0,row=1)

# Here is where I want to "print" the count on a Label
recPe1 = Label(recFrame, text=labelCount)
recPe1.grid(column=0, row=2)

recFrame.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

Every word the program will look for are three characters long, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another loop. Simply, bind `<KeyPress>` to a function then update the count.

See the example below:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext


def update(event):
    dataText = dataInput.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    
    labelCount = dataText.count("1r#")
    recPe1.config(text=labelCount)
    

root = Tk()

dataFrame = Frame(root)
recFrame = Frame(root)

dataLabel = Label(root, text="Dados").grid(column=0, row=0)

dataInput = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=3, height=10)
dataInput.bind("<KeyPress>", update)
dataInput.grid(column=0, row=1)

dataFrame.grid(column=0)

recPeTitle = Label(recFrame, text="P", width=3)
recPeTitle.grid(column=0,row=1)

# Here is where I want to "print" the count on a Label
recPe1 = Label(recFrame, text='0')
recPe1.grid(column=0, row=2)

recFrame.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks but if I need to update more than one label do I need one labelCount for every single label or is there a way to update the whole frame?

Comment: @dkol if all your labels have to be the same then there is no need for multiple labelCount you can use the same. If you have anything else to update place it under the update function and it will update everything.